# Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed."

Tags: sql-server, jsp, ssl, exception, jdbc

When I try to connect to the MS SQL Server 2017 Express instance from JSP using JDBC driver 4.2, I get the following error.

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: any firewall protections are there in the network ? if not then can you upgrade the jdbc version to the latest and try again ?

Comment: Firewall protection? How can I make the firewall allow this connection?

Comment: check with your network administrator, he can help you. before that i request you to use latest version of jdbc driver and try whether this error is coming or not

Comment: where can I get the latest jdbc driver?

Comment: just google "jdbc download for sql server 2017 "

Comment: Can you mention any trusted source other than Microsoft. I'm restricted to download from MS.

Comment: The problem is solved by using the latest jar.

Comment: you mean the latest jdbc?

Answer (score 2):

1. Edit `$JAVA_HOME\jre\lib\security\java.security`
2. Find `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=`
3. Remove `3DES_EDE_CBC`

This should fix it!