# Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.", after downgrading Db from Enterprise to Standard

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

We are using JDK 1.8.0_131, and JDBC 4.2, we have all TLSv1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 enabled, the issue started appearing after we **downgraded DB from Enterprise to Standard**. Ping to the Db works, and we can also connect to it with MS SQL Server Management Studio.

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed.".
```

We have tried the following solutions from other posts:

1. [SQL Server JDBC Error on Java 8: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766114/sql-server-jdbc-error-on-java-8-the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connect)
   It mentions, passing TLSV1 as a parameter, we tried that and it didn't work. Another answer mentions using JDBC 4.2, which we already do.
2. https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/the-driver-could-not-establish-a-secure-connection-to-sql-server/ba-p/383477
   From here, checked that “security.provider.1=sun.security.provider.Sun” is present in the  jre\lib\security\java.security file, which is present. Also checked that jre\lib has jsse.jar in it.
3. [Error: "SQL Server did not return a response. The connection has been closed."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53152863/error-sql-server-did-not-return-a-response-the-connection-has-been-closed)
   Find jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=
   Remove 3DES_EDE_CBC
   This is already not there.

Comment: Could you provide some of your code? Also does connecting to SQL Server via SQL Server Management Studio work that way?

Comment: I would suggest to upgrade back to Enterprise

Comment: Yes we are able to connect with SQL Server Management Studio